# how to delete specific map keys from a button Flutter/Dart

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I have a Map of string and doubles. I am creating a button for each key. This works fine (see photo).  On long press, I would like to delete that key/button. The issue I am having is that the key that gets deleted is always the last entered regardless if you press the first or any other key. This is a for fun project and I am willing to rewrite all of this if there is a better way. The goal for the map is to keep track of how many of that string there are. EX: "pencils":2 etc

```
for ( name in materialMap.keys)
            Container(
              child:ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(name),
                onPressed: () {},
                onLongPress: () {
                  
                  displayDeleteDialog(context,name );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

The delete dialog

````
Future<void> displayDeleteDialog(BuildContext context, String name ) async {
  //this brings up an alert dialog to input material

   name=name;

  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Are you sure you would like to remove material'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              materialMap.removeWhere((key, value) => key == name);
              //materialList.remove(materialList[indexDeleteM]);
              Navigator.push(
                context,```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ0lN.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are having trouble updating `materialMap` within the presentation layer.  The first thing would be that I would change the Map into an Iterable data structure, like List, so you can have indexes to make it easier to remove.  Then this sounds like a state management problem, which you can use a variety of libraries or methodologies such as `Bloc`/`Cubit`, `Riverpod`, `Provider`, or `Stateful Widget`.

The broad strokes are that you will store the `materialMap` as a List high in the Widget tree and then use some kind of builder each time you update the state.

**Cubit**

```
class MyCubit extends Cubit<int> {
  /// Your initial list of material
  MyCubit() : super([{"pencil":2},{"paper":1,}]);

  /// event to remove item by index
  void remove(int index) => emit(state.remoteAt(index));
}
```

```
class ButtonList extends StatelessWidget {
    const ButtonList({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => MyCubit(),
      child: BlocBuilder<MyCubit, List<Map<String,double>>(
          builder: (context, state) => state.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
             int idx = entry.key;
             Map<String, double> val = entry.value;
             return TextButton(
               child: Text(val.keys.first ?? "missing"),
               onPressed: () => context.read<MyCubit>().remove(idx),,
               );
            }
         ).toList(),
      );
    }
  }
```

**Stateful Widget**

```
class ButtonList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ButtonList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ButtonListState createState() => _ButtonListState();
}

class _ButtonListState extends State<ButtonList> {
  final List<Map<String, double>> material = [{"pencil": 2},{"paper": 1,}];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: material.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
      int idx = entry.key;
      Map<String, double> val = entry.value;
      return TextButton(
        child: Text(val.keys.first),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            material.removeAt(idx);
          });
        },
      );
    }).toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Lyod, I think your correct. I was bypassing the screen update by just calling the screen again. That bypass might be what is making it harder to track. I’m going to try your second suggestion as I understand it a bit more when I get home. Thanks